# Calculation of the AP in YOLOv4

Tags: computer-vision, data-science, darknet, yolov4

I performed object detection using YOLOv4. For one of the classes, I received an AP value of 56.79%. I extracted model prediction confidence and IoU for each of the predicted images. I also calculated precision and recall for each output (the total number of ground truths for this class is 49).

[image]

When I calculated the AP@50 with an 11-point method and with Interpolated AP method I got a value of AP of around 33%. Does Darkent use a different method of AP calculations or maybe used the wrong approach? (I used the information from this article: https://towardsdatascience.com/on-object-detection-metrics-with-worked-example-216f173ed31e)